# tagged_with on join query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, acts-as-taggable-on

I use `acts-as-taggable-on` and postgres to set tags by context such as.

```
Place.tagged_with('mytag', on: :interests)
```

This is working fine. Now, places have many people. So my question is how can I search for people with places tagged with mytag as interests?

I can see it would involve a join query but Im not sure how to replicate the tagged_with method to include the join. any help?